# python references, nested dicts and 'del' produce unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, dictionary

This is more a question out of interest.
I observed the following behaviour and would like to know why / how this happens (tried in python 2.7.3 & python 3.4.1)

```
ph = {1:0, 2:0}
d1 = {'a':ph, 'b':ph}
d2 = {'a':{1:0,2:0},{'b':{1:0,2:0}}
>>> d1
{'a':{1:0,2:0},{'b':{1:0,2:0}}
```

so d1 and d2 are the same.
However when using del or replacing values this happens

```
>>> del d1['a'][1]
>>> d1
{'a':{2:0}, 'b':{2:0}}
>>> del d2['a'][1]
>>> d2
{'a':{2:0},{'b':{1:0,2:0}}
```

The behaviour for d2 is as expected, but the nested dictionaries in d1 (ph) seem to work differently.
Is it because all variables in python are really references?
Is there a work around if I can't specify the placeholder dictionary for every instance?

Thank you!

Comment: `d['a'] is d['b']` in the first dictionary. You have the same dictionary object at both keys. This is not so in the second case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [pythontutor](http://www.pythontutor.com). If you put your code into it you will see this:

[image]

You can see that as you suspected the dictionaries in `d1` are references to the same object, `ph`.

This means that when you `del d1['a'][1]` it really deletes a key in `ph` so you get this:

[image]

To work around this you need to initialise `d1` with *copies* of the `ph` dictionary, as discussed in other answers here...

Comment: @Moses Koledoye: Thanks for the edit, sorry I accidentally reverted it so I've restored it.

Answer (score 1):

Both keys in `d1` point to the same reference, so when you delete from `d1` it affects `ph` whether you reach it by `d1['a']` or `d1['b']` - you're getting to the same place.

`d2` on the other hand instantiates two separate objects, so you're only affecting one of those in your example.

Your workaround would be [`.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) for your second reference in `d1`.

```
d1 = {'a':ph, 'b':ph.deepcopy()}
```

(You don't really need deepcopy in this example - copy() would be sufficient - but if `ph` were any more complex you would - see the above linked docs.)

Comment: thank you for the .copy() / .deepcopy()  information. Very helpful